# How to join points into overlapping polygons layer?

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, grouping

I'm using QGIS and I am relatively new to it. I have a points layer. Each point is the location of a conflict event and the attributes are the type of conflict, year of the event, number of deaths etc. I also have a polygon layer. The polygons are the areas inhabited by different groups which can overlay. Two final results work for me:

1. I want to have the number of events BY TYPE, YEAR, etc for each polygon.
2. It is also useful if I could have a table with the points and a column with the polygon attributes. In this case, if a point falls into two different polygons, I will need that point to appear twice once for each each polygon.

Please let me know whether there is a way to do at least on them in QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. Have you checked the questions tagged point-in-polygon http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-in-polygon? What information are you missing? For more info, you can check our [faq].